# InsertAdjacentHTML, element saves after refresh

Tags: javascript, insertadjacenthtml

I am able to add the elements I want, but after I refresh they disappear. How can I get the elements to save permanently while using `insertAdjacementHTML` or do I need to use another method?

Sample code:

```
function itemAdder () {
    var header = document.querySelector(".list-group");
    header.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<a>Item 1</a>')
};

document.getElementById("circle-add").addEventListener("click", itemAdder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time an item is added, you might save the container's current `innerHTML` in `localStorage`, and on page load, if anything exists in `localStorage`, populate the container with whatever's stored:

```
var header = document.querySelector(".list-group");
if (localStorage.headerHTML) header.innerHTML = localStorage.headerHTML;

function itemAdder () {
    header.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<a>Item 1</a>')
    localStorage.headerHTML = header.innerHTML;
}

document.getElementById("circle-add").addEventListener("click", itemAdder)
```

(hopefully you have a way to delete items as well - on deletion, use the same line `localStorage.headerHTML = header.innerHTML;` to save the HTML again)

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding: The second line checks if anything is set in the header and resets it what has recently been added?

Comment: It checks if anything exists in *the `headerHTML` property of `localStorage`*. The actual `header` doesn't persist across page sessions, only `localStorage` properties do.